# Componente MVC para Google Maps

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, google-maps

Atualmente estou usando o componente  [Googlemap control for Asp.Net MVC](http://www.jmelosegui.com/map/)
para rendererizar mapas do GoogleMaps.

Estou usando este componente porque vou ter que traçar a rota de um veículo vindo da base de dados via model, aí vou usar a opção de DataBinding do componente.

O problema é que estou usando ele dentro de um div com bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="content-box-header">
    <div class="panel-title">Mapa</div>
</div>
<div class="content-box-large box-with-header">
    <div id="map-canvas">


        @(Html.GoogleMap()
              .Name("map")
              .Width(750)
              .Height(350)
              .Zoom(18)
              .MapTypeId(MapType.Satellite)
              .Center(c => c.Latitude(-23.4554d)
                  .Longitude(-46.6257d))
              .Culture(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"))
              .Markers(marker =>
              {
                  marker.Add()
                      .Latitude(-23.4554d)
                      .Longitude(-46.6257d)
                      .Title("Hello World!")
                      .Icon("~/Content/img/6.png", new Size(20, 32), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 32))
                      .Draggable(true);
              }))
    </div>
</div>
```

O ruim é que o componente precisa que eu informe o valor da altura e largura do mapa a ser renderizado(Width,Height), aí o mapa deixa de ser responsivo.

Alguma forma de calcular o valor da largura/altura do div dinamicamente?

Ou algum outro componente free que possa utilizar?

Comment: Verifique neste link: http://www.jmelosegui.com/map/basic/UIControls que tem algumas informações uteis sobre o seu problema.